# i can't play pre-roll ads if flash is off

Tags: jwplayer

first, sorry for my english, 
this is my first post, i've problem to playing video pre-roll ads if flash is off, but if flash on, pre-roll ads play greatly, i've search every reference for playing pre-roll video ads in html5, but nothing, this is my code :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?=kone_url('appaux-js', 'jwplayer-5.10.js');?></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer("livestreaming").setup({
                'id': 'playerID',
                'width': '663',
                'height': '390',
                'stretching' : 'uniform',
                'controlbar.position': 'bottom',
                'autostart' : '0',
                'plugins' : '<?php echo kone_url("appaux-swf", "ova-jw.swf")?>',
                'config' : '<?php echo $config ?>',
                'modes': [
                    {
                    type: 'flash', 
                        src: '<?php echo kone_url("appaux-swf", "jwplayer-5.10.swf")?>',
                        config:{
                            'image' : "<?=thumbImage(array('path'=>$videos[0]['path_thumbnail'], 'width'=>'663', 'height'=>'382', 'type' => 'videos'));?>",
                            'file': "<?=kone_url('media-videos').$videos[0]['path'];?>",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    type: 'html5',
                        config:{
                            'image' : "<?=thumbImage(array('path'=>$videos[0]['path_thumbnail'], 'width'=>'663', 'height'=>'382', 'type' => 'videos'));?>",
                            'file': "<?=kone_url('media-videos').$videos[0]['ipad_video_path'];?>",

                        }
                    },
                    {type: 'download' }
                ]
            });
        </script>

and this is script config :

            <config>
               <ova.title>
                  '.$uri.' Video Ads
               </ova.title> 
               <ova.json>
                   {    
                    "ads": 
                        {
                            "controls": {
                                   "skipAd": {
                                      "enabled": true,
                                      "showAfterSeconds": 15
                                   }
                              },

                            "servers": [
                                   {
                                      "type": "OpenX",
                                      "apiAddress":  "$secret",
                                        "allowAdRepetition": true
                                   }
                            ],
                            "schedule": [
                            '.$video_ads.$koma.$video_ads_overlay.']},
                        "debug": {
                              "debugger": "firebug",
                              "levels": "fatal, config, vast_template, vpaid, http_calls"
                        }

                    }
               </ova.json>
            </config>
```

what can i do for pre-roll ads can be playing in html5 ? 
Thank You for attention

Comment: You are using JW5 here and OVA. OVA is a Flash only plugin. It doesn't work when Flash is not enabled.

Comment: can i play pre-roll ads video for html5 using jwplayer 5 ? I am very happy if you provide a reference for making video ads in html5

Comment: JW Player 5 does not support HTML5 ads, I'm afraid. Only JW6 supports this.